# How do I add social media icons to my code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, social-networking

This is the code i have so far.
At the end of the email, I would like to provide social icons like these ones that i found free online. And to lead them to corresponding links i have. Minus the skype.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgjeXw

```
function sendEmails() {
  var allData,counter,emailAddress,fourRowsOfData,i,lastRow,
      message,messageStart,messageEnd,numRows,
      row,sheet,startRow,studentName,subject;

  //USER INPUT
  startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  numRows = 4;   // Number of rows to process
  subject = "Camp Pursuit: Report Card ";
  messageStart = "Dear Parents,"+'\n' +'\n' +
  "Every week at Camp Pursuit, we ask the teachers to make observations about how the kiddos did." +'\n' +
  "We know that one week isn't enough to truly know a child, so we call this our " +"Glows, Grows, & Apropos." +'\n' +
    "Meaning..." + '\n' +'\n' +
    "Glows: Positive things the teacher noticed" +'\n' +
    "Grows: Areas for continued growth" +'\n' +
    "Apropos: Ways to continue your son/daughter's enrichment" +'\n' +
    "We hope you appreciate seeing what the teachers saw last week, and perhaps you can use some of"+'\n' +
    "the recommendations for further enrichment this summer.  Feel free to let us know your thoughts on the camp through our anonymous online survey."+'\n' +
     "Your feedback helps us improve the experience for all kiddos! "+'\n' + 
"Survey Link: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g4LvA9a8sdKECr1yvp5uOoPnvKACFm3HvbTBfvQGRyo/viewform?usp=send_form" +'\n' +
"We look forward to seeing your child at our programs throughout the year!" +'\n' +
"Sincerely, "+'\n' +
"The Camp Pursuit Team"
+'\n';
  //END USER INPUT

  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  allData = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow-startRow, 10);// Get All data first

  counter = 0;

  while (counter < lastRow-startRow) {
    Logger.log('counter: ' + counter)

    fourRowsOfData = sheet.getRange(startRow + counter, 1, numRows, 6).getValues();
    emailAddress = fourRowsOfData[0][0];  // First column of first row
    Logger.log('emailAddress: ' + emailAddress)

    studentName = fourRowsOfData[0][1];

    messageEnd = "";//Reset on every outer loop

    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {//loop numRows times - once for each row
        row = fourRowsOfData[i];

        messageEnd = messageEnd + '\n' +
            "Class: " + row[2] + '\n' +'\n' +
              "Glows: " + row[3]+ '\n' +
              "Grows: " + row[4] +'\n' +
                "Apropos: " + row[5] +'\n';  
    }

    message = messageStart + "\n" + studentName + "\n" + messageEnd;

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);//Send the email outside of inner loop    
    counter+=numRows;//Increment counter by number of rows to process
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use examples from codepen as they involve lots of code (e.g. for displaying hover states, etc). However, you could save the buttons as images and store them in your Drive or elsewhere.

The next step is to get the blob for your image from external URL

```
var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(yourImageUrl).getBlob();
```

or from Drive

```
   var imageBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(yourFileId).getBlob();
```

Build the string for the html body of your email. Use 'br' tags for line breaks. Wrap your images in 'a' tags to get them to link to external websites. In 'src' attribute of the 'img' tag, create a unique id for your image blob and put it after 'cid'.

```
var body = "<h1> Header </h1> <br />" +
            "<a href='www.example.com'><img src='cid:uid' /></a> Image <br />" +  
            "Content";
```

Instead of string parameters, pass the following object to MailApp.sendEmail() method. At runtime, the script will parse the string stored in 'body' variable and create html output, using cid identifiers to retrieve images from inlineImages object. The property names of 'inlineImages' object must match the ids you put created for your images in 'body'

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "recipient@example.com",
    subject: "subject",
    htmlBody: body,
    inlineImages: {

      uid: imageBlob

    }

});
```

Concatenating the string to produce html body is not the best solution though. Consider creating a reusable html template using HtmlService https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/